# sql matching criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am building a message system that allows my client to send a message to customers based on their bio profile..

I have the following tables

```
    message
    --------
    id(pk) 1
    message 'This is a message'

    message_bio
    ---------
    idPK   question_id   answer_id    message_id (fk for message table)
    1       1               4          1 
    2       2               3          1
    3       3               2          1

    customer_bio
    -------------
    id    customer_id  question_id   answer_id
    1        1            1             4 
    2        1            2             3 
    3        1            3             2 
    4        2            1             4
    5        2            2             3
    6        2            3             6

    question_table
    id     question
    1      gender etc..
```

So the Customer table is linked to Customer Bio which has the answers to the questions answered..

basically just need customer 1 to come up as it is a complete match not partial.. I have tried inner /left joins.. feels like something simple, but can't get my head around it..

any help greatly appreciated..

Comment: I have no clue what you are trying to do here. Which are the primary keys in customer_bio and message_bio? How do you relate one with the other? What's bio_q and bio_a? Instead of showing example rows with dummy data, describe the table structures and **the relationships between them**. Then people might have a better idea of what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: message_bio and customer_bio are not related directly.. they are are related by the question and answers.. so example.. message needs to be sent to gender=1, profession=2, favourite_food=4 it needs to find the customer who has the exact match

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question you want to find the customer_bio records that has the same answers for all the questions on the message.

In order to do that you need to compare the count of Customer questions to the count of the matching message records.

```
SELECT c.*, m.*
FROM   customer c 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT mb.message_id, 
                          cb.customer_id, 
                          COUNT(mb.question_id) match_count 
                   FROM   customer_bio cb 
                          INNER JOIN message_bio mb 
                            ON cb.question_id = mb.question_id 
                               AND cb.answer_id = mb.answer_id 
                   GROUP  BY mb.message_id, 
                             cb.customer_id) message_matches 
         ON c.customer_id = message_matches.customer_id 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT cb.customer_id, 
                          COUNT(cb.question_id) 
                   FROM   customer_bio 
                   GROUP  BY customer_id) customer_count 
         ON message_matches.customer_id = customer_count.customer_id 
            AND message_matches.match_count = customer_count.customer_count 
       INNER JOIN messages m 
         ON m.message_id = message_matches.message_id
```